# Route traffic through Azure Function proxy based on host header

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-function-app-proxy, hostheaders

I'm trying to serve multiple sites through function proxy.

```
Site1 =>  /docs  =>  docs.example.com/

Site2 => /docs   =>  docs.contoso.com/
```

It's possible through frontdoor. But just wondering if this is possible with Azure function proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

As of today its not possible to do that with proxies
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1987

Comment: Can this be achieved through  `Azure CDN` rules ?